# 403 Error when accessing website externally

Tags: apache-2.4

I have been tasked with allowing a certain IP access to one of our dev wordpress site which was initially setup for internal access only.

I have already setup the port forwarding however when accessing the site externally I get a 403 error, access denied. The www folder is setup with perm 755 so in theory i would of thought we would have access however in reality it is not working. I'm very new to Linux so bear with me, but if you require me to post any config files to help diagnose my issue then please do ask.

**etc\apache2\sites-enabled\000-default.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

EDIT #1
As requested here is a snippet of the access logs:
https://pastebin.com/8zDEkR32 (unable to post directly here due to less than 10 posts on site so can not post more than 5 or so URLs in a post yet)
196.52.84.52 is one of the external IP that i'm attempting to access the web server with

EDIT #2 
Have just spotted this in error.log
https://pastebin.com/z3M9EgqA

Comment: Check your log files /var/log/apache2/access.log and /var/log/apache2/error.log. If you cannot figure it out after looking at those log files, please post snippets from those log files to your question (you can edit your question).

Comment: Hi @david-w thank you for your prompt reply - I have included a snippet of the access log from last night when I was attempting to connect. You may be able to decipher it better than me.

Answer (score 0):

if the website is works on internal network, so you have to check several things.

1. check your iptables, maybe the external ip address is blocked.
2. maybe default apache2 config only allowed from internal network

for problem #1, you can allow external ip address to access the server on that port 80.

for problem #2, you can try to add some extra code, after DocumentRoot /var/www/html.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I will be checking the IP table in a moment, but i thought i'd mention that the apache2 config file matches the one for the version of the site that is currently live on a different server - with this being said it is pointing more at the iptable potentially being the issue.

However that being said, I do receive a 403 error from Apache so would that then indicate that I do have access to the server and that iptables would not be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Right so I found the issue, where i've only joined this organisation recently all of my settings were on default within my FTP client. After noticing 'Show Hidden Files' was disabled I was unable to view .htaccess file, after opening the file it become obvious that I was require to add a entry in here to allow access to the site.

Derp!

Thanks for the suggestions though, much appreciated